# ESP32 how to make SPI transfer faster

Tags: arduino, esp32

Im using a ESP32 to transfer the chip contents of a 32MB NOR Flash Chip however the transfer takes over  1 hour to transfer the whole 32MBs i was hoping theres a way to speed it up here my current code

```
uint8_t sector_buffer [512];

Serial.print("Writing NOR Dump to SD\n");
vspi->beginTransaction(SPISettings(30000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
digitalWrite(VSPI_SS, LOW); //pull SS low to prep other end for transfer
vspi->transfer(WB_READ_DATA);
vspi->transfer(0x00); // Address (three bytes, A23 bit first).
vspi->transfer(0x00);
vspi->transfer(0x00);

//open sd file here

for (int i=0;i<0x10000;i++) { // 32Mbytes / 512.
  for (int s=0;s<512;s++) sector_buffer[s] = vspi->transfer(0x00);

  //write to sd
  file.write(sector_buffer, 512);
}
digitalWrite(VSPI_SS, HIGH); //pull ss high to signify end of data transfer
vspi->endTransaction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of transferring every single byte seperately you should consider using the `SPI.transfer(buffer, size)` methode. The table found in https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/spi_master.html#transfer-speed-considerations will give you a good idea why sending single bytes is suboptimal at best. According to https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPITransfer: "In case of buffer transfers the received data is stored in the buffer in-place (the old data is replaced with the data received). "

Comment: Hello can you show me a example on how to use that method? All the samples I found are either out of date or doesn't show how I specifically use it

Comment: I am not a big fan of robbing ppl of the experience to solve an issue by themself; so here a piece of the puzzle which should help you to solve it by yourself: ```vspi->transfer(sector_buffer, 512);``` - good luck :)